# Number of numbers formed from 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3

Tags: combinatorics

How many 6 digit numbers can be formed from the set 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3? 
Would the answer be 6C2?

Answer (score 4):

The wording is potentially ambiguous, but I’m assuming that the problem is to count the distinct $6$-digit numbers that contain four $1$’s, a $2$, and a $3$. There are $\binom62$ ways to choose the two positions that aren’t $1$’s, but there are then $2$ ways to place the $2$ and the $3$ in those two positions, so there are actually $\binom62\cdot2=30$ such numbers, not $15$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{6!}{4!1!1!}=6\cdot5=30$$